# Boost compile error with VS 2008 but not 2010 or 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, visual-studio-2012

I am wondering if it is possible to compile the boost chat client example found here (the example with the 3 files: chat_message.hpp, chat_client.cpp, and chat_server.cpp):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

with VS 2008 compiler? It compiles with 2012, but not 2008 or 2010. I am using boost version 1_51

I'm compiling it from within VS 2012 but using the platform toolset for VS 2008. When i change the compiler to 2008, all of a sudden the namespace line (in chat_client.cpp) gets underlined in red by intellisense:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
```

I haven't been able to figure out what it is that is causing the 2008 compiler to fail and if there is some way to get around this (perhaps using an older version of boost?).

This is the output I get when I compile with 2008 (with #define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC):

```
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_regex-vc90-mt-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc90-mt-1_51.lib
1>c:\users\dustin\documents\boostexamples\boostchatclientexample\chat_message.hpp(70): warning C4996: 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string.h(144) : see declaration of 'strncat'
1>c:\users\dustin\documents\boostexamples\boostchatclientexample\chat_message.hpp(84): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>chat_client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>chat_client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>chat_client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::thread::detach(void)" (?detach@thread@boost@@QAEXXZ)
1>chat_client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QAEXXZ)
1>chat_client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::thread::start_thread(void)" (?start_thread@thread@boost@@AAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\dustin\Documents\BoostExamples\BoostChatClientExample\Release\BoostChatClientExample.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is it really the compiler that fails, or just Intellisense? If it's the actual compilation, what errors do you get?

Comment: I added my errors above. Also, the 2010 compiler also throws the same errors, but intellisense doesn't show the line as red. So only the 2012 compiler successfully compiles it.

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors. You don't seem to link with `boost_system` and `boost_thread` libraries.

Comment: After adding the diagnostics, I think it may be an issue with 32 bit vs 64 libraries because apparently it is linking in the `boost_system` and `boost_thread` libraries